# Accessing WSDL file when a web service is down?

Tags: web-services, soap, web

Trying to know if there is any way to get the wsdl file of a web service when it is down ?

Comment: Which technology are you using?

Comment: any technology will be fine. c# or java.

Answer (score 0):

For C# services, if you have access to the dll's you can use the following:

http://wsdlgenerator.codeplex.com/

Note: with this tool all types that you use must be within a single dll

Comment: My questions was to access the WSDL when service is down. The service might be located somewhere remotely.

Comment: If the service is down and you do not have access to the machine on which the system is installed, then you cannot access or generate the wsdl